# Implicit internal linkage not the same as explicit internal linkage ("static")?

Tags: c++, gcc, static, constants, linkage

Today I encountered a pecularity which, although probably not really important, nevertheless puzzles me. Maybe I'm just not understanding C++ correctly, too.

Some arrays inside a source file point to string literals, like so:

```
const char* a[] = { "a", "b", "c" };
const char* b[] = { "d", "e"};
const char* c[] = { "f", "g"};
```

None of these pointer arrays is ever used in any way other than being passed to `GetProcAddress` to retrieve a function pointer from a library (this is a non-blocking dynamic OpenAL/EFX/capture function loader and context creator/manager).

It eventually occurred to me that I should probably declare those variables as `static const` since they're not needed anywhere outside that very .cpp file, so making internal linkage explicit seemed appropriate. They should have internal linkage anyway (ISO14882 3.5(3)), so we're only being good citizens by making explicit what the compiler already assumes.

Doing that innocent change resulted in a 512 byte increase of executable size. Not like an additional 512b really matter, but it just didn't seem to make sense that the exact same thing would result in different code. Since `static const` is deprecated (ISO14882 7.3.1.1(2)), I tried an anonymous namespace also, with the same result.

Looking at the assembler source shows that explicit internal linkage (`static` or `namespace{}`) will move the string literals into `.rdata` rather than `.data`, and the string literals are interleaved with pointer-to-string-literal arrays, instead of having all strings and all pointers in one block, respectively. Herein probably lies the reason for the different size too -- very likely shuffling data from one section to another has hit a section size constraint. Interestingly, all 3 flavours mangle the names differently too.

Now I wonder: Am I making a fallacy, should those pointers *not* have internal linkage?

Also, in my understanding `const` is already read-only, inhowfar is `static const` "more read-only" (one goes into `.rdata` and the other does not)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your arrays are *not* declared `const`, hence they aren't implicitly internal linkage either. What you have is non-const arrays of pointers-to-const.

That said, I don't know why this affects whether the strings end up in `.rdata` or `.data`.

Comment: Oh my, of course... what a stupid, obvious mistake of mine. Indeed, it should be `const char* const a[]`, which behaves as expected, too (implicitly internal linkage, and has identical mangling). It also makes sense why the non-constant pointers-to-literal would be in `.data`, if the array isn't const. Just the literals, I don't know... I'd expect these to be readonly in any case. Still, excellent catch.